# HTML5 text rotation

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, html5-canvas

I want to rotate the text for x-axis of graph. Below is the code I am using

```
context.rotate(20*Math.PI/2);
context.fillText(name, startX + (i * barWidth) + i, chartHeight + 10, 200); 
context.rotate(-20*Math.PI/2);
```

I am rotating it back to original position after writing the text. But somehow it is not working. Working code can be found at http://intercepter.comli.com/example3.html

I have gone through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas) and have tried it but it is just not working. Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing rotated text on a HTML5 canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas)

Comment: hi Robert..I have gone through this article and have written in the question also. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating by `20*Math.PI/2` is similar to not rotating anything, 'cause :

```
20*Math.PI/2 = 10*Math.PI = 2*Math.PI
```

Not sure how do you want to rotate your text, but instead of

```
context.rotate(20*Math.PI/2);
context.fillText(name, startX + (i * barWidth) + i, chartHeight + 10, 200); 
context.rotate(-20*Math.PI/2);
```

you may try to use [transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations) like this:

```
context.save();
context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
context.translate(startX + (i * barWidth) + barWidth/2, chartHeight - 10); 
context.rotate(-Math.PI/2);

context.fillText(name, 0, 0, 200);        
context.restore();
```

See the working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzMzw/):

Comment: ooh God....sorry... I intended to use context.rotate(20*Math.PI/180); but somehow changed to /2 :( ... Updated the code here http://intercepter.comli.com/example3.html ... BTW setTransform doesn't seems important !!

Comment: @antnewbee Yes, `setTransform` here is not so important, but it is good practice to reset transform matrix, when you start your transformations.In other case it could be hard to track all transformations.