# Textarea in a foreignObject

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, svg, textarea

I am having some problems typing into a `textarea` created with a svg.

Here is the code:

```
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px;position:fixed;top:100px;left:50px;'>" +
               "<textarea cols='30' rows='10'></textarea>" +
                 //"<em>I</em> like <span style='color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;'>cheese</span>" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
            var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
            var img = new Image();
            var svg = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
            img.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
            img.src = url;

            var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
            doc.write(html);
            doc.documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns", doc.documentElement.namespaceURI);
            var html = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc);
```

It generates what I need, a `textarea`, into a canvas, but blocking write/edit. What's wrong?
I reused that code from: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Answer (score 0):

You got exactly what you've done: You `drawn` a textarea on a `canvas`.

Is not possible to make it interactive like a `Textarea DOM Element` without manage manually every thing.

Comment: Thanks chumkiu
so... what I can do? I realy need to make a text area inside a canvas...

Comment: You can create a regular textarea and set the position on the canvas. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815447/add-a-textarea-inside-the-canvas-at-the-current-mouse-position