# Can't draw text upside down in Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw text on a canvas, and then rotate the canvas so the text is displayed upside down.  However it still does not display upside down.  The bitmap is displayed upside down but the text isn't.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);
    canvas.rotate(180, bm.getWidth()/2, bm.getHeight()/2);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas might help.

Comment: Rotate the canvas first and then draw the text on the rotated canvas.

Comment: @Leco With a rotation [you still don't get](http://jsfiddle.net/4dQ9V/) upside down text. See my answer below

Comment: @Raffaele Well, it works for me on a SurfaceView implementation. 
 
 My code is as follows:
  
 canvas.save();
 canvas.rotate(-90, padding, screenHeight/2);
 canvas.drawText("Text", padding, screenHeight/2, paint);
 canvas.restore();

Comment: @Raffaele OK, I just saw your link. I was thinking about vertical text. My code displays text vertically, not upside down.

Comment: Sure, 90° is for vertical text. And 180° is still rotated. You need to invert the sign of the `y` to get upside down, and that's what `scale(1, -1)` does

Answer (score 3):

When you transform a canvas, you are actually performing an update on the [transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), so that subsequent painting calls will be transformed. As an example, if you want to "pad" your painting, you first translate the canvas:

```
canvas.translate(10.0f, 0);
```

and then paint a Rect on (0, 0):

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 10);
```

The rectangle will be draw with its origin translated to (10, 0), so that it'd be as if you had called `drawRect(10, 0)`, because every 2D point is multiplied by the current transformation matrix. The same applies for other [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), like rotation and scaling. So if you want to draw upside down text you have to apply the transformation **first**, and **then** painting.

By the way, to draw text actually upside down, the transformation you are looking for is not *rotation*, but a *swap* of the Y coordinate:

```
canvas.scale(1, -1);
canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);
```

Also, be sure to understand the difference between a `Canvas` and a `Bitmap`: the former is the Android API class used to expose the various painting APIs, the latter is an array of the actual pixels in the image (and as I recall until 2.3 it's allocated from native libraries, so never forget to call `Bitmap.recycle()` or you'll soon end up the available space and get `OutOfMemoryException`s.