# Watermark in jqplot

Tags: jquery, html, charts, html5-canvas, jqplot

How can I add watermark to chart in jqplot?
I saw this question already here, but it was not answered.
I have found once a hint, but I can't find it any more. The advice had somethiung to do with canvas..

Comment: I think you can find what you want around html5-canvas. Please see [this link on SO] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771050/how-to-draw-watermark-in-html5-canvas-with-dynamic-rotation-value) which can give you a god start