# Rotate html5 canvas text from its center point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to rotate the HTML5 canvas text with dynamic X, Y value from it's center position. I used the below code as mentioned in the stackoverflow link [HTML5 rotate text around it's centre point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172501/html5-rotate-text-around-its-centre-point) . but text is always rotating from start point. I need from center point rotation. This is my code.

```
 this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
 this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 this.ctx.translate(options.x , options.y);
 this.ctx.rotate(options.labelRotation * Math.PI / 180);
 this.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 0);
```

Anyone let me know how to rotate the text from center point of the text.

Thanks,
Bharathiraja.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/d40xr8nL/

If its not working on your end:

- be sure your options properties are valid.
- wrap the code in ctx.save & ctx.restore (because transforms are cumulative).

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var x=150;
    var y=150;
    var labelRotation=45;
    var label="This is some text.";

    animate();

    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        //
        ctx.save();
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.translate(x , y);
        ctx.rotate(labelRotation * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.fillText(label, 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        labelRotation++;
        draw();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```