# Insert chart values on each bar on JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas, charts

I've made a chart on a JavaScript canvas using

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

and then inserting the bars with values from an array called `arrayValues`. The resulting chart is this: [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s1io.png), but I can't add the values from the array for each bar, to see them on the chart. I'd like them to appear on the top of each bar or vertically inside each bar. Can someone show me how, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is some information about drawing text to a canvas [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text). If you want the text to be printed sideways to fit, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas).

Comment: I'll look on those links, thank you!