# Rotate context does not work for HTML5 canvas text

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've successfully been able to fill in text on an HTML5 canvas element but have not been able to do the same for rotated text.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
ctx.font = '15px Arial'
...
ctx.fillText('50',232,190)
ctx.fillText('40',272,190)
ctx.fillText('30',312,190)
ctx.fillText('20',352,190)
ctx.fillText('10',392,190)

/* Everything above this point is rendered perfectly */

ctx.save()
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2)

ctx.fillStyle = 'orange'
ctx.font = '15px Arial'
ctx.textAlign = 'left'
ctx.fillText('10',32,190)
ctx.restore()
```

I used this article for reference: https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/writing-rotated-text-on-a-javascript-canvas/

Resulting image from the code above (other canvas-rendering code not essential to understanding this problem has been omitted):

[image]

I have tried clearing my cache several times but it's still the same output, with none of the rotated text shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing rotated text on a HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason. It turns out I needed to translate the text because the rotation of Pi/2 radians made it go outside the canvas. The implementation was rectified by adding the following before rendering all the rotated text:

```
ctx.rotate(Math.PI)
ctx.translate(-480,-72)
```