# Adaptive text rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create adaptive rows with text.
It's need to repeat text to end of row. Row width is equal to window width. And after that repeat rows to end of page. Page height is equal to window height. Also text is rotated to 45deg.

[Example](https://oneworldoneface.com/404)

I can make it with checking parent element width & height and fill it before size will be equal or bigger than window. But if text rotated to 45deg its to hard to me. Any suggestions how to that right?

Comment: Yep. It's "404" text. When you resize window number of text repeats change adaptive

Comment: Is your struggle with rotating text or making the already rotated text fill the space?  If the former, something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167928/drawing-rotated-text-on-a-html5-canvas/5400970#5400970 would be helpful.  If the latter, you know the height and width, so you can calculate the diagonals and use that as the limiter.